# Windows 7 Explorer File Sorting Alphabetically

Tags: sorting, windows-7, windows-explorer

Is it only me or Windows 7 has a weird file name sorting scheme? The example is below. 
I have 3 text files:

```
This File.txt
This is File.txt
This.txt
```

When you will sort this file manually, it should be:

```
This.txt
This File.txt
This is File.txt
```

But Windows 7 gives me:

[image]

Any idea on how to sort the files like how I listed above?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [StrCmpLogicalW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function: that's the one used in explorer if I'm not completely mistaken.